# Wy my GOPATH/src contains few directories just after installed?

Tags: go, gopath

I've just installed Golang on my machine, and I set up GOPATH.
But when I navigate to my go/src I see that src folder contains `./sourcegraph.com`, `./golang.org`  and  `./github.com`. Also `GOPATH/bin` and `GOPATH/pkg` also no empty.
So I have several questions:

1) I know how to use `./github.com` folder for pushing my code to github, but why it contains , from box, some other not mine projects inside such as `acroca, cweil ... and other` ? Can I clear this folder?

2) What I should do with `golang.org` folder, can I remove it ?

3) What I should do with `sourcegraph.com` folder, can I remove it ?

4) Can I clear `bin` and `pkg` from preinstalled binaries and packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you not only installed the `Golang` but also install/configure `Visual Studio Code` IDE with Go Extension. Those *alien* repositories were created when the extension installs needed tools. The full list of tools can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Go-tools-that-the-Go-extension-depends-on). Or probably other similar IDE/extension which depends on those tools.

1. Yes you can clear the sources, since the IDE depends only on the compiled binary, and the sources are only needed during compilation.
2. Same as (1). Refers to [Golang SubRepositories](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SubRepositories)
3. Same as (1)
4. For now, you can clear the content of `pkg` directory but don't remove the directory. In the future, when you install some packages/libraries, the compiled version may be created under the directories, so don't remove it. For `bin` directory, don't remove the files inside it, because the IDE (Go Extension) depends on them.

But, since I don't know exactly what else you've done, I think before you completely remove them, try just to move them outside your `GOPATH` or take a backup and see whether your `dev environment` works as expected.

Comment: You are  right, I've installed VSC. Thank you for explanation and advises.